# A question about algebraic indicator functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-curves, characters, congruences

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Consider the indicator function $g_f : \mathbb{Z} \to \{1,0\}$ given by
\begin{align*}
g_f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if there exists $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = mf(r) + k$} 
\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
As a special case, let $f(x) = x$.  Then there is an integer solution for $n = mf(x) + k$ if and only if $n \equiv k \mod{m}$, and we can write
\begin{align*}
g_f(n) = \frac{1}{\phi(m)}\sum_{\chi} \chi(n)\bar{\chi}(k)
\end{align*}
where the sum runs over the Dirichlet characters $\chi \in \text{Hom}((\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$, and $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

I am wondering, is there any way to get a nice expression for $g_f$ (like the one above) for $f(x) \neq x$?  Does anyone know if indicator functions like this have been studied before?  I imagine one of the problems is that the relation $n \sim k$ if and only if there exists $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = mf(r) + k$ is not an equivalence relation when $f(x) \neq x$.